# openssl with CA file and CRL file

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509certificate

Hi,

I'd like to extract information from an certificate authority taking into account revocation with OpenSSL. I have the CA, the CA of revocation, revocation certificate and the authentification certificate.
They are all converted to the PEM with Openssl beforehand, here is my command:
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile CAFile.pem  -untrusted CRLSign.pem -CRLfile CRLfile.pem -crl_check  -extended_crl certToDecrypt.pem

I'm absolutely sure that the certificate corresponds to their naming.
However, OpenSSL always returns a syntax error and I didn't found any answer on the internet. Can someone help and explain me how does it works ?

output :

```html
usage: verify [-verbose] [-CApath path] [-CAfile file] [-purpose purpose] [-crl_check] [-engine e] cert1 cert2 ...
recognized usages:
 sslclient  SSL client
 sslserver  SSL server
 nssslserver Netscape SSL server
 smimesign  S/MIME signing
 smimeencrypt S/MIME encryption
 crlsign    CRL signing
 any        Any Purpose
 ocsphelper OCSP helper
```

I understand that OpenSSL tells me that an option is missing/wrong, but according to my technical documentation, that's how I'm supposed to do it.

Thanks in advance.